# Error al intentar agregar elementos a un objeto en Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando añadir nuevos elementos a un objeto en Javascript pero me sale el siguiente error. **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'diagnostico' of undefined.** A continuación muestro el fragmento del codigo donde realizo la siguiente acción:

```
var procedimientos = response.procedimientos;
var camposProcedimientosHC = {};
procedimientos.forEach(function(campos, index){
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].diagnostico = campos['codigoDiagnostico'];
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].servicio = campos['servicio'];
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].codigo = campos['codigo'];
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].nombre = campos['nombre'];
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].valor = campos['valor'];
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].codigoActividad = campos['codigoActividad'];
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].fechaServicio = $("#fecha_atencion_historia").val();
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].codigoActividadDeta = campos['codigoActividadDeta'];                
});
```

Estoy recibiendo de **response.procedimientos** un array que seria el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que puedo esta realizando mal?

Comment: Negativo ahora me sale ahora **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined**

Comment: Pimero necesitas agregar el emento, probablemente con `camposProcedimientosHC.push(campos);` y después solo modificas (o agregas) la fecha de atención.

Comment: Por cierto, la propiedad `diagnostico` no viene incluida en la respuesta, en todo caso, sería `codigoDiagnostico`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te indica el error, estas intentando acceder a la propiedad de un objeto no definido.

En el codigo cuando incializas `camposProcedimientosHC` es un objeto vacio, en el foreach estas intentando dar valor a propiedades de una propiedad de `camposProcedimientosHC` que no existe y por eso te salta error.

```
var procedimientos = response.procedimientos;
var camposProcedimientosHC = {};
procedimientos.forEach(function(campos, index){
    camposProcedimientosHC[index] = {}
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].diagnostico = campos['codigoDiagnostico'];
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].servicio = campos['servicio'];
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].codigo = campos['codigo'];
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].nombre = campos['nombre'];
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].valor = campos['valor'];
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].codigoActividad = campos['codigoActividad'];
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].fechaServicio = $("#fecha_atencion_historia").val();
    camposProcedimientosHC[index].codigoActividadDeta = campos['codigoActividadDeta'];                
});
```

Comment: Funciono para mi, muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Estas intentando tratar una variable de tipo `OBJECT` como un tipo `Array`.

**Intenta cambiando esto:**

```
var camposProcedimientosHC = {};
```

**a esto:**

```
var camposProcedimientosHC = [];
```

Comment: `camposProcedimientosHC[index].diagnostico` seguirá arrojando el mismo error.

Comment: Sigue arrojando el mismo error

Comment: Intenta con `camposProcedimientosHC.push(campos)` con la variable `camposProcedimientosHC` de tipo array.

Comment: @JuanCarlosPeñaM. Antes de asignar ningún campo haz esto: `camposProcedimientosHC[index] = {}`

Comment: No, por que no voy a capturar todos los campos que me traen en **response.procedimientos**.

Comment: @JuanCarlosPeñaM. Muestranos un ejemplo de como quieres que quede la variable `camposProcedimientosHC` al final de hacer el loop.